# Testing Crypto module in FreeBSD kernel

Tags: cryptography, kernel, freebsd, kernel-module

I recently added a cipher to the FreeBSD Crypto kernel module, but i am having trouble testing it from the application layer and verifying that it works.

I managed to add my cipher and compile the kernel successfully, but i want to use my cipher in the application layer. How can i write a small program to use this new cipher ?

Answer (score 0):

The API is described in [crypto(9)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypto&sektion=9).